# Multiple threads in python2 and python3 got different result of cpu usage

Tags: python, gil

Due to GIL, multiple threads usage in python is limited. I tested using two dead loop threads. Here are my test result.

python 3.8.1
[image]

python 2.7.5
[image]
Cpu usage for python2.7 is over 100% near 200%.

Here is my system info:

LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch

Distributor ID: CentOS

Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

Release:    7.9.2009

Codename:   Core

2 cpu cores.

And here is the test file.
test.py

```
from threading import Thread


class Async:
    def start_async(*args):
        fun = args[0]

        def start_thread(*args, **kwargs):
            t = Thread(target=fun, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
            t.start()

        return start_thread

    @start_async
    def new_thread2(*args):
        while 1:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Async().new_thread2()
    Async().new_thread2()
```

So, I'm confused with this phenomenon. I thought they should be similar. Why?

Comment: Those look like separate processes, not just separate threads within a single process (they have distinct PIDs even). Can you clarify exactly what you're running?

Comment: Post the python code.

Comment: What about the other 3.x versions? Have you checked the release notes? A tight, infinite loop is something that can be detected statically and handled differently, so why shouldn't a newer version improve on the handling there?

Comment: If I run `top` with the `-H` option, to make it show all threads, I can sort of reproduce the 3.8 display on `python3.9` running on FreeBSD 13. But both threads show the same PID, like they should.

Comment: Which threading library are your versions of Python linked with? Given that we see three python processes with different PID's, could it be you are still using LinuxThreads?

Comment: I used  `top -H -p` to show this. And I tried python 3.6.8, it showed the same with 3.8.5.  About the threading library, I have no idea. python2.7 is installed by system default. Others are installed by myself. Let me check this.

Comment: `top -H -p` the column: PID, it should be TID? Because I use `ps -T`, The SPID is the same with what `top -H -p` shows.